# Condition is always false since types 'string' have no overlap error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-statements

There is a variable and I am reading the input from the user. For example:

```
let userName;
readUserNameFromUser(userName); // Consider this method will read the userName from user 
if (userName === '') {
  //Do Something;
}
```

On this condition `userName === ''` I am getting this error:
`Condition is always false since types '(IFlagBase<any, boolean> & {type: "boolean", allowNo: boolean, default?: Default<boolean>}) | (IFlagBase<any, string> & {type: "option", helpValue?: string, default?: Default<any | undefined>, multiple: boolean, input: string[], options?: string[]} & {completion?: ICompletion})' and 'string' have no overlap` 
Can anyone help me how to resolve this and why it is occuring?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never assign anything to `userName`, so it will always be `undefined` when you perform the test.

Comment: Function arguments are passed by value, not by reference. So if `readUserNameFromUser` assigns to its parameter variable, it won't update your variable.

Comment: You're passing in `username` as an argument but not assigning the result of whatever `readUserNameFromUser` is to anything. Is `readUserNameFromUser` an async function? Is it a `prompt`?

Comment: My check is for if the user enters a userName as empty string, I want to handle that case. ```readUserNameFromUser```, it's a prompt.